# phpunit output numbers meaning

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

When I run phpunit I have following output

```
phpunit:

PHPUnit 4.8.16 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

................................................................. 65 / 93 ( 69%)
............................

Time: 354 ms, Memory: 10.25Mb

OK (93 tests, 119 assertions)
```

What is 65 ? and 69% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every dot PHPUnit prints out is a single test run by the framework and after each line, PHPUnit will tell you how far it got.

So in your case, `65 / 93 ( 69%)` means that 65 out of 93 tests have been executed, which is 69% of all tests.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it would nice to have a ref to phpunit documentation where I can get explanation of that ? Anyway, may I ask you Why it runs only 65 tests ??

Comment: I'm afraid I can't find a chapter in the documentation about this. Anyways, the output does not mean it only executes only 65 tests - this is just the first shown line of tests. The remaining tests are shown as the dots in the next line

Answer (score 2):

As PHPUnit executes a test, it displays a marker on your screen to indicate its progress.

It means that by the end of the first line of dots (one dot for each test), phpunit had completed 65 tests out of 93 total tests, which is 69% of the test run. There are 65 dots in that first line, showing that all 65 of those tests have been run and passed, without any fails, skips, ignores, etc. Correctness/failure of tests is shown by different colours/characters than ., such as a red F for a failed test

After each completed display line, PHPUnit shows the number of tests completed, total of all tests, and %complete.

The second line has 28 dots, showing the results for tests 66 through 93, at which point the run is 100% complete. Because it isn't a complete line of dots, but the run of all tests has actually completed, it doesn't show the numbers again; but will show detailed results for any errors or failures that occurred before returning to the command line prompt

No doc is provided for this

Hope this help

Comment: thanks for your reply, because storyteller was earlier I was marked his answer as a right one.